# Calculating the slope between each value and time step - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

First off, here is my data:

```
    val slopes  time
0   11  0.0     1
1   11  0.0     2
2   11  0.0     3
3   06  0.0     4
4   05  0.0     5
```

For each timestep, i'd like to calculate the differences between the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [.diff()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html#pandas-series-diff) (thanks to @JohnE) as to the df.val - df.val.shift(1) I initially proposed. However ...  this must be a dupe.

Looking at the docs we find that:

> def diff(arr, n, axis=0):
>       """
>       difference of n between self,
>       analogous to s-s.shift(n)

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'slopes': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0},
 'time': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5},
 'val': {0: 11, 1: 11, 2: 11, 3: 6, 4: 5}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#df['diff'] = (df.val-df.val.shift(1)).fillna(0)
df['diff'] = df.val.diff().fillna(0)

print(df)
```

Returns

```
   slopes  time  val  diff
0     0.0     1   11   0.0
1     0.0     2   11   0.0
2     0.0     3   11   0.0
3     0.0     4    6  -5.0
4     0.0     5    5  -1.0
```

Comment: actually can just do `df.val.diff()`

Comment: @JohnE Yesss.. of course. I knew there was a shorter version. But this is what it does under the hood I guess.